# How to get error variance for each item in lavaan cfa?

Tags: r, r-lavaan, factor-analysis

I want to extract the error variance for each item (i.e. indicator) from a lavaan CFA.

```r
library(lavaan)

HS.model <- ' visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9 '

fit <- cfa(HS.model, data = HolzingerSwineford1939)
summary(fit, fit.measures = TRUE)
```

I know I can extract the lambdas with `inspect(fit, what = "est")$lambda` . How can I get the error variances for each item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lavInspect(fit, what = "est")$theta`

This is the entire covariance matrix of residuals.  The diagonal has residual variances.